# How to change Flipview object dynamically using c#

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app

i am developing app for windows phone. i am using flipview to show detail. this flipview contains three controls in it and changing view using swipe. i want to change the view on click of button.

See my Code :

```
<FlipView x:Name="flip" Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" Grid.Column="0" Margin="0,0,0,0.333" Grid.RowSpan="2">
            <FlipViewItem>
                    <Button Foreground="White" Background="Black" x:Name="btnAdd" Content="Add" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" Tapped="btnAdd_Tapped" ></Button>
            </FlipViewItem>
            <FlipViewItem>
                <Button x:Name="btny2" Content="mov" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Tapped="btny2_Tapped" ></Button>
            </FlipViewItem>
            <FlipViewItem>
                <Button x:Name="btnUpdate" Content="Upd" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Tapped="btnupdate_Tapped" ></Button>
            </FlipViewItem>
            <FlipViewItem>
                <Button x:Name="btnRemove" Content="Rem" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="3" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Tapped="btnRemove_Tapped" ></Button>
            </FlipViewItem>
        </FlipView>




private void btnAdd_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            flip.SelectedIndex++;

        }

        private void btnupdate_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            flip.SelectedIndex++;
        }

        private void btny2_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            flip.SelectedIndex++;
        }

        private void btnRemove_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            flip.SelectedIndex++;
        }
but it is not working at all.
```

Comment: In what way does it not work? How does the actual behavior differ from the desired behavior? Incrementing SelectedIndex should advance the page. Click is a more appropriate event than tapped, but otherwise the code looks superficially fine.

Comment: hi,it is not working only by changing the index. it is work after changing the  property of flipview "flip.UseTouchAnimationsForAllNavigation = false;"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On button click event just increase/decrease selected index..

```
private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    SelectedIndex++;
}

private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    SelectedIndex--;
}
```

Comment: i have already mention it. increasing/decreasing index not working at all.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

in .xaml

```
<FlipView x:Name="flip" Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" Grid.Column="0" Margin="0,0,0,0.333" Grid.RowSpan="2">

    <Button Foreground="White" Background="Black" x:Name="btnAdd" Content="Add" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" Tapped="btnAdd_Tapped" ></Button>

    <Button x:Name="btny2" Content="mov" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Tapped="btny2_Tapped" ></Button>

    <Button x:Name="btnUpdate" Content="Upd" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Tapped="btnupdate_Tapped" ></Button>

    <Button x:Name="btnRemove" Content="Rem" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="3" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Tapped="btnRemove_Tapped" ></Button>

</FlipView>
```

in .cs

```
private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var newItemIndex = (flip.SelectedIndex + 1)
    flip.SelectedIndex = newItemIndex;
}

private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var newItemIndex = (flip.SelectedIndex - 1)
    flip.SelectedIndex = newItemIndex;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found some work around for same if you put the button outside the flipview and then try to change the index of same then its work
Please look into the following code , Using Grid or Canvas we can easily put the button on Flipview

xaml

```
 <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">



    <FlipView x:Name="SlideHub"  ManipulationMode="Rotate" FlowDirection="LeftToRight"     UseTouchAnimationsForAllNavigation="True" Grid.Row="1"  >

        <FlipViewItem  >

        </FlipViewItem>

        <FlipViewItem  >

        </FlipViewItem>

        <FlipViewItem  >

        </FlipViewItem>

        <FlipViewItem >
        </FlipViewItem>

    </FlipView>


    <Image Tapped="slideBankingNext_tapped" Grid.Row="0" Width="40" Margin="0 10 10 20" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Source="/Images/welcome_next.png"  />

</Grid>
```

C# Code

```
 private void slideBankingNext_tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var newItemIndex = (SlideHub.SelectedIndex + 1);
            SlideHub.SelectedIndex = newItemIndex;
    }
```